# question about admin.py list_display

Tags: django, django-admin

```
#admin.py
class GameListAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['game', 'position']
    ordering = ('position',)

class GameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'status']
    actions = [make_published]

#models.py
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class GameList(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    position = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.game.name
```

I'm trying to show game.status in GameListAdmin's list_display but not 
sure how to do a backwards lookup using the ForeignKey in Admin.py

Any ideas?

Comment: @Rob B - I moved your code inline, so that this question will stick make sense once dpaste.com's auto-deleted your snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
def get_status(obj):
    return '%s' % (obj.game.status)
get_status.short_description = 'Status'

class GameListAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['game', 'position', get_status]
```

See the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).

Answer (score 2):

You can always define your own column, like the doc explains : http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

For example :

```
class GameListAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ['game_status', 'position']
   ordering = ('position',)

   def game_status(self, obj):
       return obj.game.status
   game_status.short_description = 'Game status'
```